# Task with malloc() in C

Tags: c, malloc

I'm a beginner programmer, I know the basics of C++ and JS but currently I need to learn C and I struggle with one of the test task.

Basically, I need to create a program that will dynamically allocate memory with malloc(). I need to keep giving the program name and the score of the student until I decide that's enough students. With the rest of the task I believe I can deal myself, but now my program crashes after second loop and I don't know what's wrong.

```
    char decision;
int x = 0;
char tempname;
float tempscore;
char *name = malloc(x *sizeof(char));
float *score = malloc(x *sizeof(float));

printf("Name and score of the student \n");

do{
    printf("Name \n");
    scanf("%s", &tempname);
    name[x] = tempname;
    printf("Score \n");
    scanf("%f", &tempscore);
    score[x] = tempscore;
    printf("Continue? y/n \n");
    scanf("%s", &decision);
    x++;
} while(decision=='y');
```

There is probably a mistake with allocating the memory for char tables, but I really struggle with this and would be grateful for help.

Comment: `x *sizeof(char)` well since `x` is `0` you're allocating exactly zero bytes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you should really do this with a linked list, but we'll try to make this happen with an array.

To start, you need to create a dynamically sized array of pointers to strings.

We're going to use imaginary memory addresses. Let's say we have 4 names, and they are arranged as so in memory:

```
0x10000: "Adam"
0x10010: "Jonathan"
0x10020: "Mark"
0x10030: "Zach"
```

We need an array that looks like this:

```
[0x10000, 0x10010, 0x10020, 0x10030]
```

This is the first array you need to malloc. Each element of this array is of type `(char *)`, because the array holds pointers to strings. The type of the array itself is a pointer to these strings, so the array's type is `(char **)`.

We're going to call this, "names_array", and we'll start by keeping track of how many names we have, and size this array appropriately.

```
unsigned int num_names = 0;
char ** names_array = malloc(num_names * sizeof(char *));
```

When we read in a name, we need some temporary space to read it into. We're going to change:

```
char tempname;
```

To:

```
char tempname[128];
```

Now we need to add this to our array, but we only allocated space for 0 entries. We need to re-allocate memory. There's a function, `realloc`, which does this for us. `realloc` will take a pointer to some memory, resize that memory allocation to the new size we give it, and if required copy over the old memory.

```
names_array = realloc(names_array, (num_names + 1) * sizeof(char *));
```

We need to create a new string to hold our string in tempname, and we want to set that as the new value in names_array. We can do this the hard way:

```
names_array[num_names] = malloc(strlen(tempname) + 1);
strcpy(names_array[num_names], tempname);
```

Or use `strdup` which does this for us in one foul swoop.

```
names_array[num_names] = strdup(tempname);
```

After this, we increment `num_names` by `1`, and continue looping.

Your code to read in a name should look something like:

```
scanf("%s", &tempname);
names_array = realloc(names_array, (num_names + 1) * sizeof(char *));
names_array[num_names++] = strdup(tempname);
```

Your code for floats will be similar, but look more like:

```
scanf("%f", &tempfloat);
floats_array = realloc(floats_array, (num_floats + 1) * sizeof(float));
floats_array[num_floats++] = tempfloat;
```

It's important that you understand this code is terribly unsafe, but it seems like you're tat the point where you just need to understand some basics of how C works before you start learning how to use it safely. I hope this helps.

Comment: If you said "really should do this with a structure type", then I'd be happier than with the "really should do this with a linked list" comment.  You can do it with a linked list; it can also be done with arrays — preferably one array of a structure type, but two parallel arrays can also be made to work.